# night mode is not working properly - why?

Tags: android, android-night-mode

I have applied a dark mode using preference screen as:

```
  <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="default"
        app:entries="@array/themes_labels"
        app:entryValues="@array/themes_color"
        app:key="theme"
        app:title="@string/Theme"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"/>
  </PreferenceCategory>
```

and arrays are defined as

```
<resources>
  <array name="themes_labels">
    <item>"Default"</item>
    <item>"Light"</item>
    <item>"Dark"</item>
  </array>

  <string-array name="themes_color">
    <item>"Default"</item>
    <item>"Light"</item>
    <item>"Dark"</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Now, in `MainActivity`'s onCreate, I want to change the theme as:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
    } else {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
    }
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
//    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    String theme = sharedPref.getString("theme", "Default");
//    Toast.makeText(this, theme, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (theme.equals("Dark")) {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else if (theme.equals("Light")) {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    } else {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
      } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
      }
    }
```

Now, the problem is, with `Light` or Default (even when `default` is `dark mode`, like battery save is on), everything is fine. But, if, dark mode is chosen, then I am facing many problems, like not applied in a fragment or even leading to crash in some cases.

I am very new to android and don't understand why is this happening. Kindly help.

**An attempt to solve this problem is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60313831/startactivityforresult-should-be-used-error-only-in-dark-mode)**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164414/11158194 check this

Comment: @HardikTalaviya: that I have checked, where you have defined your own methods to enable things. I will go that way only when I am sure AppComaptDelegate has some problems.

Comment: If you want to add dark mode so you need to do some as answer.

Comment: Actually, I am not convinced.  Can you please explain to me why other modes are working and for `NIGHT_MODE_YES`, I must need that?